# Объединение значений таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как получить список адресов одного города по следующей структуре одним запросом?

<sub>Москва, Ленина, 38/1</sub>
<sub>Москва, Ленина, 20/2</sub>

```
Type 2:Город, 3:Улица, 4:Дом
```

<sub>unit.sql</sub>

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| Unit      | Type      | Name      | Parent      |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| 1         | 1         | Root      | null        |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| 2         | 2         | Москва    | 1           |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| 3         | 3         | Ленина    | 2           |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| 4         | 4         | 38/1      | 3           |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| 5         | 4         | 20/2      | 3           |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| 6         | 3         | Кабельная | 2           |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| 7         | 3         | Ивовая    | 2           |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| 8         | 2         | Челябинск | 1           |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| 9         | 3         | Бабушкина | 8           |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| 10        | 3         | Безрукова | 8           |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: На MS SQL? да простейшим CTE...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так

```
SELECT t1.Name + ', ' + t2.Name + ', ' + t3.Name
FROM _table AS t1
     JOIN _table AS t2 ON t2.Parent = t1.Unit
     JOIN _table AS t3 ON t3.Parent = t2.Unit
WHERE t1.Name = 'Москва';
```

> Москва, Ленина, 38/1
>   Москва, Ленина, 20/2